# HTML/JavaScript/jQuery: on("click", ...) and variable incrimenting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an app to help me in the job finding process. Basically, 1. I have an array of company websites, 2. a button to click to load companiesList[i] in a new tab, and 3. a

div to add the website contained in companiesList[i] to keep track of how many and which websites have been visited for the current session.

The 2 main problems I'm having are that 
1. the function I have for on("click",...) runs when the page loads rather than when I click on the button, and when I click the button the only thing that happens is that the console displays "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."
2. My current index keeps reseting (or not incrementing at all) to 0, so even if I get the button working I'm still left with the same website loading over and over again, instead of loading the next url contained in the array.

Here's my code so far:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Next Company's Website Button">
            <input type="button" id="nextWebsiteButton" name="filter" value="Next Company's Website Button" />
        </div>


        <div id="Current Session">
            <p>
            </p>
        </div>

    <script src="companiesList.js"></script> /*Sample for StackOverflow: var companyList = [
"http://visual.ly/", "http://zesty.com/"];*/
    <script>
    var i = 0;
    var countForSession = 1;

    var nextCompany = function nextCompany() {
        i++;
        var win = window.open(companyList[i], '_blank');
        win.focus();S
    };

    $("#nextWebsiteButton").on("click", nextCompany());


    //For use with on("click")
    var runProgram = function() {
        //load next website
        //i++ for array index
        //Add current website to html div text, format: countForSession + ". " + "company " + i + companyList[i] + \n
    };

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is executing immediately is because of the following line:

```
$("#nextWebsiteButton").on("click", nextCompany());
```

Change it to:

```
$("#nextWebsiteButton").on("click", nextCompany);
```

By adding the parenthesis to the function, you are telling the javascript compiler to execute the function immediately and use the results of that function as the click handler.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That also seems to have largely solved the incrementation problem as well. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Parker Yes, by using the variable "nextCompany" as the handler, you will now see the function being executed correctly each time you hit the button.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra `S` for some reason and you shouldn't have the parentheses. Here is the updated code:

```
var i = 0;
var countForSession = 1;
var companyList = ["http://visual.ly/", "http://zesty.com/"];

var nextCompany = function() {
    var win = window.open(companyList[i], '_blank');
    win.focus();
    i++;
};

$("#nextWebsiteButton").on("click", nextCompany);


//For use with on("click")
var runProgram = function() {
    //load next website
    //i++ for array index
    //Add current website to html div text, format: countForSession + ". " + "company " + i + companyList[i] + \n
};
```

You will also need to put the `i++` after if you want to get the first index. I'd also add an if/else to check if the next page exists or not.
Here is an updated fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyhzzqa1/1/)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I got the S part, but can't find an edit button. Thanks alot though.

Comment: @Parker added a fiddle link to check if the next page exists